# After adding view, I get this: "Server Error in '/' Application". How can I fix it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agZqH.png) after running the program.  In the view section in MVC, I have added a view.  The error is shown after execution.

Comment: Please provide more details.  Are you running the program standalone or in Visual Studio?  Do you have other views and only this one doesn't work?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Just view is not enough. You need to make sure you have a controller with a corresponding action (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller). Once done you can add a view (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view). Your URL in the result should look like https://localhost:44345/[controller]/[action] (e.g. https://localhost:44345/random if added as Random action to HomeController or Index action to RandomController).

Comment: You cannot call a .cshtml file directly. You need to call its associated controller method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.